# Using Regex to capture something from email HTML

Tags: c#, regex

so i am trying to capture a specific value from email html.The part of email is,

[image]

i want to capture **9/7/2018** from email the HTML source of the part containing this date is:

```
<table cellspacing=
=3D=220=22 cellpadding=3D=220=22 width=3D=22200=22 border=3D=220=22 align=
=3D=22left=22 class=3D=22left innertable=22 style=3D=22background:=23ffffff=
;border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;=22>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td width=
=3D=22200=22 align=3D=22left=22 valign=3D=22top=22 style=3D=22line-height:2=
2px; font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:=232a2a2a; text-=
decoration:none;=22>Date of Purchase:</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                   =20
                                                        <table cellspacing=
=3D=220=22 cellpadding=3D=220=22 width=3D=22288=22 border=3D=220=22 align=
=3D=22right=22 class=3D=22right innertable=22 style=3D=22background:=23ffff=
ff;border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;=22>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td width=
=3D=22200=22 align=3D=22right=22 valign=3D=22top=22 style=3D=22line-height:=
22px; font-size:20px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:=23636363; text=
-decoration:none;=22>

**9/7/2018**

</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                       =20
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width=3D=2250=22 cl=
ass=3D=22gutter=22></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <table cellspacing=3D=220=22 ce=
llpadding=3D=220=22 width=3D=22600=22 border=3D=220=22 class=3D=22table=22 =
style=3D=22background:=23ffffff;border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:=
0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;=22>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td width=3D=2250=22 cl=
ass=3D=22gutter=22></td>
```

i am using c# regex match can used more than once (like for first expression we can find the whole tag containing the **DATE** and from second expression we can find the date from the Tag  ) 
I tried some expressions but nothing worked for me.

Comment: You should consider a [HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) to extract values from HTML code (e.g. [HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434519/parsing-html-using-agility-pack)).

Comment: source code is suitable, not image.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod post updated

Comment: @RanaJawad if you change it to string,  you can match it easliy like `\*\*(.+)\*\*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to parse your html into a string.

Now you can use Regex to find you date:

```
MatchCollection dateFound = Regex.Matches(YOUR_STRING_NAME, "[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]{4}");
```